# Oracle Autoincrement Functionality: Triggers or Oracle JDBC CallableStatement in 11.2?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, database-performance

Which is the best way (in terms of insert performance) to implement autoincrement functionality in Oracle (11.2) when you need to retrieved the newly generated key using JDBC?

I know there are identity columns in Oracle 12, but I'm stuck with 11.2 right now.

Like many others, I have had no luck in getting the JDBC getGeneratedKeys() to work with Oracle. I ended up having trigger in my Oracle (11.2) database that acts like a MySQL autoincrement function and inserts the NextVal from a table specific sequence to act as its primary key whenever there is an insert into that table. This made getting the newly inserted key difficult though, I ended up doing a 2nd query to get the newly generated key.

More recently I discovered CallableStatement with return values and I see how these could be used to do everything with 1 call.

Is this last method generally a faster way of doing inserts when you also need that newly generated key or is there a better option for me that I am missing?

Comment: Can you not use oracle sequence object(s)?

Comment: [This](https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/sequence-driven-primary-keys-which-is-better-call-nextval-in-the-insert-statement-or-in-a-row-level-trigger/) and [this](https://www.krenger.ch/blog/oracle-primary-key-sequence-performance/) links could be helpful to you.

Comment: You can test yourself what side effect JDBC will give. I think it will be cheaper to use two queries.

Comment: Hi Jim, in both cases described above I am using the sequence object. With the callable statement I use .nextVal of the sequence for my insert and then return the result with the returning clause.

Comment: Svaor - that first link is great! The 2nd link is Oracle 12. I'm confused though, reading the 1st link it sounds like using the CallableStatement (without the trigger) should be faster due to trigger overhead?

Comment: ozborn, article on the 2nd link has the same conclusion as I see (47s/1m30s for Oracle 11g).

Comment: The mechanics of calling a trigger and performance impact are explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1743241/835000).

Comment: I think the only true answer for your question is to try and benchmark real test in your environment.

Comment: I read the rest of the original 2nd link - you are right, this does apply - it looks like it is 47s inserting my primary key from a sequence, versus 1m30s using a trigger to do it. The remaining question is how much worse is the overhead of a callable statement returning the value versus a 2nd database call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got interesing result in my mini-benchmark and decide to share it.

The test code:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

import java.sql.*;

public class TriggerPerformanceTest {
    private static final int STEPS_COUNT = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521/oradev", "user", "pass");

        prepare(connection);

        final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch("mini-bench");

        testTrigger(connection, stopWatch);
        testSequence(connection, stopWatch);
        testSeparateCalls(connection, stopWatch);

        JdbcUtils.closeConnection(connection);

        System.out.println(stopWatch.prettyPrint());
    }

    private static void testTrigger(Connection connection, StopWatch stopWatch) throws SQLException {
        final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_table_trigger (text) VALUES (?)", new String[]{"ID"});
        stopWatch.start("with trigger");
        for (int i = 0; i < STEPS_COUNT; i++) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "test");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            final boolean next = resultSet.next();
            Assert.state(next, "Expected not empty result set with generated keys");
            final long id = resultSet.getLong(1);
            Assert.state(id > 0, "Expected generated key value");
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(resultSet);
        }
        stopWatch.stop();
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(preparedStatement);
    }

    private static void testSequence(Connection connection, StopWatch stopWatch) throws SQLException {
        final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_table_sequence (id, text) VALUES (sq_test2.NEXTVAL, ?)", new String[]{"ID"});
        stopWatch.start("without trigger");
        for (int i = 0; i < STEPS_COUNT; i++) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "test");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
            final boolean next = resultSet.next();
            Assert.state(next, "Expected not empty result set with generated keys");
            final long id = resultSet.getLong(1);
            Assert.state(id > 0, "Expected generated key value");
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(resultSet);
        }
        stopWatch.stop();
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(preparedStatement);
    }

    private static void testSeparateCalls(Connection connection, StopWatch stopWatch) throws SQLException {
        final PreparedStatement preparedStatementSeq = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT sq_test3.NEXTVAL FROM dual");
        final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_table_generated (id, text) VALUES (?, ?)");

        stopWatch.start("separate calls");
        for (int i = 0; i < STEPS_COUNT; i++) {
            final ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatementSeq.executeQuery();
            resultSet.next();
            final long id = resultSet.getLong(1);
            JdbcUtils.closeResultSet(resultSet);
            preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "test");
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
        stopWatch.stop();
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(preparedStatementSeq);
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(preparedStatement);
    }

    private static void prepare(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        try {
            statement.execute("DROP TABLE test_table_sequence");
            statement.execute("DROP TABLE test_table_trigger");
            statement.execute("DROP TABLE test_table_generated");
            statement.execute("DROP SEQUENCE sq_test1");
            statement.execute("DROP SEQUENCE sq_test2");
            statement.execute("DROP SEQUENCE sq_test3");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            //ignore
        }

        try {
            statement.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table_sequence (id NUMBER, text VARCHAR2(10))");
            statement.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table_trigger (id NUMBER, text VARCHAR2(10))");
            statement.execute("CREATE TABLE test_table_generated (id NUMBER, text VARCHAR2(10))");
            statement.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE sq_test1 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20");
            statement.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE sq_test2 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20");
            statement.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE sq_test3 START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 20");
            statement.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_increment BEFORE INSERT ON test_table_trigger FOR EACH ROW\n" +
                              "BEGIN\n" +
                              "  SELECT sq_test1.NEXTVAL INTO :new.id FROM dual;\n" +
                              "END;");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            statement.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE test_table_sequence");
            statement.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE test_table_trigger");
            statement.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE test_table_generated");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
StopWatch 'mini-bench': running time (millis) = 27430
-----------------------------------------
ms     %     Task name
-----------------------------------------
09214  034%  with trigger
08916  033%  without trigger
09300  034%  separate calls
```

The conclusion: the difference quite small... to take it into consideration.

PS. Dedicated Oracle 11.2.0.4, LAN 1Gb/s, Java 1.7.0_65.

Comment: Looks good except it doesn't look like testSequence and testTrigger actually get the auto-incremented key from the sequence?

Comment: What do you mean? `SELECT sequence_name, last_number FROM user_sequences WHERE sequence_name LIKE 'SQ_TEST%'`: sq_test1/5001, sq_test2/5001, sq_test3/5001. All ids are filled with natural numbers.

Comment: I'm trying to get performance including getting the auto-incremented key. So either testSeparate (which you have) or doing a prepareCall and returning the key. The testSequence and testTrigger don't actually get the primary key (although you can infer it). Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated answer with new test code. It gets generated keys. The results are same as I see.

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to get my getGeneratedKeys functionality going (since I am getting my generated key back by using a call with a return value) but it is good to know there isn't much performance difference here so I've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Like many others, I have had no luck in getting the JDBC getGeneratedKeys() to work with Oracle

That is actually quite easy.

The following works for me with a trigger and Oracle 11.2 and driver version 11.2.0.3.0 (and 11.2.0.43.0)

```
create sequence foo_seq;
create table foo (id integer not null primary key, some_data varchar(20));
```

The trigger:

```
create trigger foo_trg 
  before insert on foo
  for each row
begin
  :new.id := foo_seq.nextval;
end;
/
```

And the Java code:

```
String insert = "insert into foo (some_data) values (?)"; 
PreparedStatement pstmt = conection.prepareStatement(insert, new String[]{"ID"});

pstmt.setString(1, "bla");
pstmt.executeUpdate();

ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
while (rs.next()) {
  long id = rs.getLong(1);
  System.out.println("The generated ID was: " + id);
}
rs.close();
```

If you don't want the trigger because of performance considerations, the above code works without a trigger, if you change the insert statement to use the sequence:

```
String insert = "insert into foo (id, some_data) values (foo_seq.nextval, ?)";
```

Comment: I tried that but I think I ended up with an operation not supported error if I remember correctly. That's why I ended up with the callable statement approach described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552260/plsql-jdbc-how-to-get-last-row-id/3552353#3552353

Comment: @ozborn: then you are probably using a _completely_ outdated driver version. The 11.2.0.4 driver will definitely support that.